# image is snapping back to old location, translate, android, xml

Tags: java, android, android-animation

what I am trying to do is to animate an image from current position to the new one by following

#### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate
    xmlns:android       ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta  ="0"
    android:toXDelta    ="0"
    android:fromYDelta  ="0"
    android:toYDelta    ="-100"
    android:duration    ="2000"
    android:fillAfter   ="true"
     />

</set>
```

#### Java Code

```
        ImageView   logo01             =    (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo01);
        Animation   animation01        =    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        animation01.reset();
        logo01.clearAnimation();
        logo01.startAnimation(animation01);
```

However, at the end of animation, the image is snapping back to the old postion. How can we avoid that situation so that at the end, image will be at new position.

Comment: The key is anim.setFillAfter(true);

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar issue. I ended up using a dynamic animation instead of xml:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-100);
anim.setDuration(2000);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
logo01.setAnimation(anim);
```